# Evaluate $ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\Big[\frac{2n}{k}\Big]-2\Big[\frac{n}{k}\Big]$.

Tags: analysis

> Evaluate
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\Big[\frac{2n}{k}\Big]-2\Big[\frac{n}{k}\Big],
> $$
>   where $[x]$ means the largest integer that no more than $x$.

Let $\Delta=\Big[\frac{2n}{k}\Big]-2\Big[\frac{n}{k}\Big]$, I found that 
$$
\Delta=
\begin{cases}
1,&\mbox{$\Big[\frac{2n}{k}\Big]$ is odd.}\\
0, &\mbox{$\Big[\frac{2n}{k}\Big]$ is even}.\end{cases}  
$$

By trying several cases for small number, I found that the cases $\Delta=1$ are quite rarely.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For fixed (large-ish) $n$, for which (spcifically, how many) $k$ is $\lfloor\frac nk\rfloor=m$?